# Is there a way to configure Notepad++ to open single files without tabs, but open with tabs when I open Notepad++ by itself?

Tags: notepad++

When I open a file with Notepad++, it also opens all the last-open tabs, but I only want it to open with the file I chose. However, if I just open Notepad++ by itself, I *would* want all of the last-opened files in tabs. Can it be configured to do this?

Comment: The quickest hack I am thinking of is using two Notepad++ installation. One for normal works with many files opened. Another with just to open single files as you've said.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Nah, I don't want to installs. Actually, I just now thought of something. If there's a command line switch to force it to open a single tab, I might be able to edit the Windows command line string used to open a file in Notepad++. Will see if such a switch exists and give that a try tomorrow

Comment: Yep, seems like `notepad++ -nosession license.txt` works. Should be able to get that to be the default command for single files. Will add as answer tomorrow once I figure it out